# Remove noise line from the following captcha

Tags: captcha

I have the following captchas, each captcha contains a noise line which is of the same color as the characters. How can I automatically detect and remove the noise line and avoid the overlapping pixels of the characters removed simultaneously?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]